# Get all nodes with empty taxonomies

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm trying to fetch all nodes who's term reference field has no value or NULL.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'mycontenttype', '=')
    ->condition('field_grade_level.entity.name', '');

    $nids = $query->execute();
    return $nids;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, giving empty results. Can anyone help what's wrong with the query?

Comment: you can also try replacing statement like this: $query->condition('field_grade_level.entity.name', NULL, '=');

Answer (score 2):

You query is looking for nodes that are tagged with a term that has an empty label. Obviously that's not what you want. What you're looking for is notExists():

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'mycontenttype', '=')
  ->notExists('field_grade_level');

$nids = $query->execute();
return $nids;
```